# save Linked List in Notepad.txt

Tags: java, format, notepad, objectoutputstream

I draw many triangle polygons and store it in  Linked List. My problem is that, when I store the drawing in a Notepad file, the data is unreadable (weird symbol). When I try to print it using println the output is like this  java.awt.Polygon@1d6096.

How to store the coordinate of the polygon in Notepad?

```
... 
java.util.List<Polygon> triangles = new LinkedList<Polygon>();
String pathname = "eyemovement.txt";
...
int[] xs = { startDrag.x, endDrag.x, midPoint.x };
int[] ys = { startDrag.y, startDrag.y, midPoint.y }; 
triangles.add(new Polygon(xs, ys,3));

...
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   if(e.getSource() == saveBtn){
      try {
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pathname);
      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
      oos.writeObject(triangles);
      oos.flush();
      oos.close();
      fos.close();
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Trouble writing display list vector");
  }
}
```

---

EDITED:

I have tried all the suggestions but still I can't managed to get the output as the following. I have tried the "Printwriter" as well, but I cant solved the problem. Help me, please, my head is so heavy with this :-(

I draw the triangles, make changes, and store it in Linked List. After finished drawing, and make changes, I click save button and save it in Notepad.txt with hope that I will get the output in Notepad like this:

40 60 50   this line represents vertices Xs of triangle 1
40 40 50   this line represents vertices Ys of triangle 1

60 80 70   triangle 2
60 60 70

100 120 110     triangle 3
100 100 110

Comment: And after you store the co-ordinates in a text file do you want to be able to read them back and re-create the polygons?

Comment: yes, actually I want to use that coordinate in my other Java program. I wanted to store the three vertices of a triangle . Is it possible to save the coordinates in Notepad?, and when I open the Notepad file I can see coordinate number (x1y1,x2y2,x3y3) instead of weird number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody actually posted the absolute simplest way to do this, so here it goes.

Take a `Polygon p`, output a string representing the x/y coordinates of `p` (assuming `p` has at least 1 point) of the form "(x1 y1, x2 y2, x3 y3, ...)":

```
System.out.print("(" + p.xpoints[0] + p.ypoints[0]);
for (int i = 0; i < p.npoints; i++) {
  System.out.print(", " + p.xpoints[i] + " " + p.ypoints[i]);
}
System.out.println(")");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to store co-ordinates, and only want to write one way (into the file) then you should write an override method on your Polygon:

```
String toString() {
  return this.x + ", " + this.y;
}
```

or something similar.

Comment: This is what I means. I just want to store the coordinates in a form of (x1y1,x2y2,x3y3) but I dont know how to do it ...is it different with just: 

triangles.add(new Polygon(xs, ys,3));

Comment: If you want to serialize the objects, you should read about serialization. You can serialize to a binary (not text) format (which will be unreadable to you), which represents how the objects are stored in memory. That can then be read again by another Java program. Optionally, you can save as XML. This is readable to you and to Java.

But you should really be clear about what you are doing. Treat the two objectives as separate things: writing a file that you can read (that's a user interface feature) and writing a file that Java can read (an internal functionality feature).

Answer (score 1):

Of course the data is unreadable. It is "Data", not "Text". You have to read the file again with the `ObjectInputStream` class. Use the method `readObject(); This method returns an Object. Of course you have to cast it on this way:

```
Object o = ois.readObject(); // ois is the ObjectInputStream
List<Polygon> list = new ArrayList<Polygon>((List) o));
```

I think you just want to save the triangle to continue working with it after closing your program.

Answer (score 0):

I start with a test case.

```
import java.awt.Polygon;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class PolygonTest extends TestCase {
    public void testToString() throws Exception {
        Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
        polygon.addPoint(0, 1);
        polygon.addPoint(1, 1);
        polygon.addPoint(1, 0);
        assertEquals("(0,1;1,1;1,0)", polygon.toString());
    }
}
```

I'm assuming here that you are using the awt Polygon class.  This test fails, because awt's Polygon class doesn't override the default behavior.  But Polygon has lots of good stuff in it you don't want to lose (maybe), so to add the new behavior we want (a toString() method), let's change this just a little bit:

```
import java.awt.Polygon;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class PolygonTest extends TestCase {
    public void testToString() throws Exception {
        Polygon polygon = new Triangle();
        polygon.addPoint(0, 1);
        polygon.addPoint(1, 1);
        polygon.addPoint(1, 0);
        assertEquals("(0,1;1,1;1,0)", polygon.toString());
    }
}
```

This doesn't even compile, because the Triangle class doesn't exist yet.  So let's create it (I'm using eclipse; I'll run QuickFix to create the class for me):

```
import java.awt.Polygon;

public class Triangle extends Polygon {

}
```

And now the test compiles, but fails as before.  So let's write the toString() method:

```
import java.awt.Polygon;

public class Triangle extends Polygon {
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("(");
        for (int i = 0; i < npoints; i++) 
            sb.append(String.format("%s,%s;", xpoints[i], ypoints[i]));
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1); // get rid of the final semicolon
        sb.append(")");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

and now the test passes.

Note that I changed the format a little from what you requested, because I think you probably want to be able to distinguish between the point (5, 17) and the point (51, 7).